# How to use the "Reply-To:" field from the email header in a Salesforce email-to-case

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Our company has an external application that sends an email to our help-desk email, to generate an email-to-case ticket. The from email is static, generic, company address, ie; no-reply@company.org.  The header of the email has the "reply-to:" field set to the members email who actually triggered the email to be sent, ie: "member@gmail.com". Up until recently (late July 2021), when the case was created, the suppliedEmail aka Web Email would be set to the reply-to email address, "member@gmail.com". Now it is using the "from" email, and I cannot figure out how to change this back to the "reply-to" email. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Keith, did you ever resolve this issue?